# How to redirect imgur images to another domain with URL masking?

Tags: redirect, proxy, cpanel, http-status-code-301, imgur

Famous image upload website imgur.com is forbidden/blocked in my country. Except VPN, there is no way to access to the imgur links.

Let's say i have a domain name called om-gur.com (i made up the name) and i bought a hosting service.

This is the link i want to see: https://imgur.com/xxxxxx.jpg

What i want is that when i change the domain name imgur to om-gur, i can see the imgur image and the url i should see is this:

https://om-gur.com/xxxxxx.jpg

Like hosting the image at another url, like some kind of proxy(?)

---

I tried 301 redirect (cPanel), some url masking/frame tests, some htaccess changes. Nothing worked.

---

In summary, i want some kind of proxy for my personel use.

The link i visit: https://imgur.com/xxxxxx.jpg

(manually changing imgur to om-gur then press enter.)

I see the target image at: https://om-gur.com/xxxxxx.jpg